# Is there a way to pause execution a UWP console app's main thread while still handling events?

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I'm prototyping an app (UWP console app for now) that is event driven. The app operates on newly created files on the system and I'm using `StorageFileQueryResult.ContentsChanged` to watch for them but am unsure what I should be doing to keep the process alive while waiting for the events. I'm currently using an infinite while loop (which works). Surely, there has to be a better way?

I'm using c++/winrt but any general UWP solution be applicable.

Sample code snipped below:

```
int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();

    Windows::Storage::StorageFolder folder{ Windows::Storage::StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync(SOME_PATH).get() };
    auto queryOptions = Windows::Storage::Search::QueryOptions(Windows::Storage::Search::CommonFileQuery::DefaultQuery, NULL);
    auto query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
    query.ContentsChanged(Query_ContentsChanged);
    
    auto files = query.GetFilesAsync().get();
    for (auto const& f : files) {
        std::wcout << f.Name().c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    while (1) {} // Keep process alive
}
```

Comment: Is this really a UWP console application, or a console application that consumes Windows Runtime types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you could use `getchar()` or `system("pause")` to block the console thread.

Another way you could use is lock, please check the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m(mtx);

    Windows::Storage::StorageFolder folder{ Windows::Storage::StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync(L"C:\\test1").get() };
    auto queryOptions = Windows::Storage::Search::QueryOptions(Windows::Storage::Search::CommonFileQuery::DefaultQuery, NULL);
    auto query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
    query.ContentsChanged(Query_ContentsChanged);

    auto files = query.GetFilesAsync().get();

    cv.wait(m);
    //getchar();
    //system("pause");

}
```